# Adding a new element to another screen's list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list in `Page_2.dart`:

```
final List<Trans> transactions = [
    Trans(false, 20),
  ];
```

that takes a custom class widget, `Trans` that takes a Boolean and a double and displays them in a `Row`, and I have button to add a new element to `transactions`,

```
RaisedButton(
 onPressed: () {
  setState(
          () {
       transactions.add(
       Trans(true, -50));
       },
     );
   },
  child: const Text("Add Transaction"),
),
```

and I want to have a button inside `page_3.dart` that does the same thing which is adding a new adding a new `Trans` to `transactions`

Comment: Can you give some more details? What all widgets are there on page 2 and page 3? Are you using any state management?

Comment: I just `stateful widgets` in both, in page 2 I have the custom class `Trans` that is stored in a list `transactions` and displayed using  `ListView` and I have a button that adds new `Trans` to the the list using `setState`, in page 3 I only have a single button that I want it to add new `Trans` to the list in page 2 when clicked.
@bluenile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is pass the function 'add transaction' from 'Page 2' to 'Page 3'. You have to make sure that the function 'add transaction' accepts 'Trans' as a parameter and it also calls setState for Page 2. In Page 3 you have to pass your 'Trans(true, -50)' as the parameter to the 'add transaction' function that is received from 'Page 2'. The 'add transaction' function may be run in the onPressed method of RaisedButton on 'Page 3'. Please see the code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

final Color darkBlue = const Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

extension Ex on double {
  double toPrecision(int n) => double.parse(toStringAsFixed(n));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Flutter Demo App"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  void _addTransaction(Trans transaction) {
    setState(() {
      transactions.add(transaction);
    });
  }

  final List<Trans> transactions = [
    const Trans(myBool: false, myDouble: 20),
    const Trans(myBool: true, myDouble: -50),
    const Trans(myBool: false, myDouble: 110),
    const Trans(myBool: false, myDouble: 35.5),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .7,
          child: Scrollbar(
            showTrackOnHover: true,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: transactions.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: transactions[index],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final rnd = math.Random();
            _addTransaction(
              Trans(
                myBool: rnd.nextBool(),
                myDouble: rnd.nextDouble().toPrecision(2) + rnd.nextInt(100),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: const Text("Add Transaction"),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Page3(addTran: _addTransaction),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: const Text("Page 3"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Trans extends StatelessWidget {
  final myBool;
  final myDouble;

  const Trans({Key key, this.myBool, this.myDouble}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Text("Transaction: ${myBool.toString()}  ${myDouble.toString()}")
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Page3 extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function addTran;
  const Page3({Key key, this.addTran}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _Page3State createState() => _Page3State();
}

class _Page3State extends State<Page3> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Page 3"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () => widget.addTran(
            const Trans(myBool: true, myDouble: 50),
          ),
          child: const Text("Add Transaction"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note : even though in my example code above the widget 'Page 3' is in the same file. You may make a separate library for 'Page 3' as usual by importing material.dart.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. If you wish, kindly like (up-vote) the answer if it helped solve your issue.

Comment: Hey, thanks this solved my problem but I wanna ask what does `addTrans` do in Page 3, and how does it add a `Trans` to the list ?@bluenile

Comment: If you notice there is a Function _addTransaction(Trans transaction)  on Page 2. This function accepts one parameter `Trans`. The function merely adds the Trans passed to it to the List<Trans> transactions. Now what we are doing is we are sending this function to Page 3. When the `Add Transaction` button is clicked on Page 3, what happens is Page 3 passes the Trans(myBool: true, myDouble: 50) to the function. The function updates the list & also updates the state of the app. In Dart, everything is object including functions, you can store function in a variable & pass it around like a variable

Comment: it's been a while but I have another question (if you don't of course) : if I navigate between these 2 pages using `Main` (opening them individually rather than using page 2 to open page 3) how can I send `_addTransaction` to page 3 ?do I have to use Streams or Providers ?  @bluenile

Comment: Using Provider would be best solution here. Provider would make your Trans class available to your entire app.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there are two methods of widget interaction: callbacks (when one widget provides a callback and other one call it back) or streams (when one widget provides a stream controller and other one uses those controller to send events to stream). Callbacks and events are processed by widget-initiator.

1. Create a `ValueSetter` parameter in `Page3` widget and create it like:

```dart
// in Page2
final page3 = Page3(callback: (trans) {
  transactions.add(trans);
}

// in Page3
onPressed: () {
  widget.callback(Trans(...)); // if Page3 us stateful
}
```

2. Create a `StreamController<Trans> state member in` Page2`and pass it as parameter to`Page3`.

```dart
// in Page2
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  controller.stream.listen((trans) {
    transactions.add(trans);
  });
}
// in Page3
onPressed: () {
  widget.controller.add(Trans(...));
}
```

Comment: Where should I implement `void initState()` ?
I am getting `error: Undefined name 'controller'.`
@BambinoUA

Comment: This is the method of `State` class. It must be overriden.

Comment: I put not completely working source code. I just describe the idea. I wrote you need to declare StreamController (those controller). It looks you should read more about callbacks and streams.